# Discriminated Unions of Objects With Common Properties

Tags: typescript

### Background

I have a type `Payload` defined like this:

```
type Payload =
  | {
      category: Category.ROUTE_POINT;
      id: string;
      newValues: Partial<RoutePoint>;
    }
  | {
      category: Category.UNASSIGNED_ROUTE_POINT;
      id: string;
      newValues: Partial<UnassignedRoutePoint>;
    };
```

I also have a function called `ArrayUtils.updateObject` defined like this:

```
export default class ArrayUtils {
static updateObject = <T>(oldObject: T, newValues: Partial<T>) => 
{
  // code omitted
}
```

### Issue

I have a reducer that takes in an action object containing a payload of type `Payload`. I narrow the type of payload down based on a check of the `category`, but for some reason my compiler has an issue with passing `action.payload.newValues` in my `ArrayUtils.updateObject` function because it isn't sure that `action.payload.newValues` is of type `Partial<RoutePoint>`.

If I assigned `action.payload.newValues` to some other variable, the compiler has no issue.

**Why isn't my compiler aware that narrowing has occurred to trust that my action.payload.newValues is the proper type?**

```
if (action.payload.category !== Category.ROUTE_POINT) return routes;

// action.payload.newValues is already narrowed
// Hovering over action.payload.newValues shows it is of type Partial<RoutePoint>
const newValues = action.payload.newValues; 
return routes.map((route) => {
  return {
    ...route,
    points: ArrayUtils.updateItemInArray(
      route.points,
      action.payload.id,
      (p) => {
        // return ArrayUtils.updateObject(p, action.payload.newValues); does not work
        return ArrayUtils.updateObject(p, newValues); // this works
      }
    ),
  };
});
```

Comment: can you kindly provide a reproducible example in the typescript playground? Thanks @RouteMapper